# Can I use packer with QEMU builder to generate centOS 7 base (ISO) image?.

Tags: centos, qemu, packer, cloud-init

I have read the documentation for QEMU builder and I am wondering if it's possible to generate ISO CentOS base image with cloud init custom configuration using QEMU.